# codeigniter php

Tags: codeigniter

I downloaded the latest pyrocms zip file and I noticed something strange happening. On windows using xampp-lite 1.7.3 or 1.7.2 the installation process is successful and I am able to go to the admin login page.
But as soon as I type the given username and password and attempt to login, apache in xampp crashes and an error comes up with send to MS etc so I switch to ubuntu which is a virtual machine on my system and in ubuntu it installs successfully as well but when I attempt to see the login page it just goes blank. I even used a full xampp 1.7.2 install for linux and nothing. Maybe this is important, I have other client websites running on both win and ubuntu running off CI and no problem. I have no error codes cos I don't see any errors in the logs of xampp. do have any suggestions cos this bums me out, atleast before I look for other lamp and wamp stacks for windows and linux? thanks

Comment: Can you try to put:
ini_set('display_errors',1);
in index.php right below error_reporting(E_ALL);
and on Linux box see what the blank page turned into?

Comment: nothing shows on linux still white and on windows still apache crashes.

Comment: Does Windows event viewer show up any errors?

Comment: yeah with 1.7.3 now this is what event viewer has for me:
Faulting application httpd.exe, version 2.2.12.0, faulting module php5ts.dll, version 5.3.0.0, fault address 0x0003406f.
event id:1000
 what do you think? I am trying to reach eventid website to see but it's good to hear from several good heads!?!

Comment: looking at what was mentioned at eventID.net, a simple windows restart might solve the problem even though this is such a generic error it's hard to pin down what is really wrong. another suggestion is that I should change the faulting application either upgrade or i figured downgrade the app which in my case is httpd. wat do u think?

Comment: I would try to download and install php from php.net website and see if those libraries throw up the same error. You could try the non thread-safe version as opposed to php5ts.dll where ts stands for thread safe

Comment: ok let me try that and see what gives! thanks for your time. I will still post my findings back here so you could check if you can.

Comment: make sure u configure apache to use new dll version and restart it afterwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If downloading php from php.net and replacing the one that comes with xampp, reconfiguring and restarting apache doesn't fix it. Try commenting php_threads.dll extension in php.ini

To reconfigure xampp apache edit xampplite\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf
php module section:

```
#
# PHP-Module setup
#
LoadFile "/xampplite/your_new_php_dir_or_same_if_you_deleted_and_replaced/php5.dll"
LoadModule php5_module modules/php5apache2_2.dll

<IfModule php5_module>
    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.phps$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
    </FilesMatch>

    PHPINIDir "/xampplite/php"
</IfModule>
```

At least we can try to narrow it down bit more

Comment: I think this xampp version is just faulty with the "threadsafe" feature. I downloaded bitnami LAMP stack for linux and installed it. it ran but the big let down is that it seems pyrocms has some problems it's self as when I enter the demo@example.com and password it gives me a blank screen but I noticed the url is kinda wrong cos it should have index.php in it as in http://localhost/pyrocms/index.php/admin/login but it shows as ...pyrocms/admin/login. dunno what you think though? 
SORRY and by the way, the answer you gave might be right but I think I just have a bad xampp install

Comment: http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite/ - see here how to get rid of index.php and maybe get pyrocms to work

Comment: Looked at the .htaccess file of the pyrocms folder and index.php is part of the entire url process.